# Why is this code to find the minimum number in an array assuming the first element is smallest?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
     int a,array[100],min,c,b=0;

     printf("Enter a number that you wish: \n");

     a=GetInt();

     printf("Now Enter %i Independently \n",a);
     for(int b=0; b<a; b++)
     array[b]=GetInt();
     min = array[0];
     for ( c = 0 ; c < b ; c++ )    
     {
         if ( array[c] < min ) 
            min = array[c];
     }   

     printf("Minimum value is  %i.\n", min);
     return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter a number that you wish:
4
Now Enter 4 Independently 
2
3
1
4
Minimum value is  2.
```

But I am sure the minimum number is 1 — what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is `b` is local variable to the this `for` loop

```
for(int b=0; b<a; b++)
//this b will get destroyed when this for loop terminates
```

And later you are using it in your termination condition in another condition

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < b ; c++ )
//the b here is the other b which you defined in the 1st line of the program
//             int a,array[100],min,c,b=0;
//the b is this for loop is this one ^^
//this b still has value 0
```

---

The solution would be to use `a` in both the `for` loop conditions

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < a ; c++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int b=0; b<a; b++)
```

You declare `b` in loop again , it overshadows the previous `b` declared ,so value of `b` outside `for` loop does not change and remains `0` and your loop doesn't iterate.

Don't declare `b` inside `for` loop again . Just write this -

```
  for(b=0; b<a; b++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `b` used in `for ( c = 0 ; c < b ; c++ )` is `0` because
it is initialized as zero and `for(int b=0; b<a; b++)` won't affect its value.

Try changing the for loop to `for ( c = 0 ; c < a ; c++ )` (use `a` instead of `b`).